# Scatterplot for multiple regression in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, regression, scatter-plot

I have four features and a dependent(X). I want to plot a graph with the predicted regression line and the feature values. I went through the documentation but I can't figure out how to represent everything in a scatter plot.

Comment: Could you give some sample data ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code to get you started, it fits a simple quadratic and scatterplots the raw data and fitted curve along with calculation of RMSE and R-squared. The example uses a non-linear fit in case you would like to try fitting non-linear equations.

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import scipy.stats

xData = numpy.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.0, 6.6, 7.7])
yData = numpy.array([1.1, 20.2, 30.3, 40.4, 50.0, 60.6, 70.7])


def func(x, a, b, c): # simple quadratic example
    return (a * numpy.square(x)) + b * x + c


initialParameters = numpy.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0])

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, initialParameters)

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```